# Human recognition using Template matching

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I am using Emgu-CV to identify each person in a big room.
My camera is static and in-door.
I would like to count the number of persons who visited the room, that is I want to recognize each person even if I got the images in different angles at different times in a day.

I am using Haar classifiers to detetct the face, heads and full body from the image and then I am comparing this with the already detected image portions using template matching so that I can recognize the person. But I am getting very poor results. 
Is this the right approach for this problem ? can anyone suggest a better approach ?

Or is there any better libraries available which can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think Template Matching is the weak point in your system. I would suggest training a Haar cascade for each person individually that will result replace (detecting + recognition) with (detect a precise object). Sure if the number of people you want to recognize is rather small. Or you can use some other stuff like SURF but note their licence.